# try catch exception handling scenario

Tags: java, error-handling, try-catch

I am looking to handle a multi-level error handling scenario, where I have a test looks somehwat like this:

```
void tester() {
    String fileName = Path.of(myDir, "file_1.lo").toString();
    assertThrows(
            Error.class,
            () -> TheCompilerClass.parent_method_called_by_testcase(fileName),
            "Expected parse error to be thrown for this test"
    );
    assertTrue(getStdErr().contains("Failed to compile"));
}
```

And this invokes the code I have developed where upon exception I am trying to send back something that will result in bool: True at the assertTrue statement above.

My code structure is like this:

```
parent_method_called_by_testcase() {
  try {

  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Failed to compile ");
    //how do I return the right thing? 
    //STDERR statements can't be returned back to test case invoking methoid?
  }
}

child_method {

  //this finds that exception has occurred and should pass it up the chain
  //should this have a throw statement? or just a return?
  if (exception) {
    tell the parent so that parent can tell the testcase
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arguably, log lines like the one you mention are not part of what is generally tested in unit tests. More commonly, we test end functionality. For example, if the child method encounters a case where we throw an exception, does the parent method catch that? In other words, does the parent method throw an exception as well? This is an example of an assertion that one might write in a unit test.

Here, based on your test, your, `assertThrows` means that you expect the parent method to throw an exception here. So in your `catch` block, you would do some logging but ultimately `throw e` if you want the parent to throw if the child does.

```
parent_method_called_by_testcase() {
  try {
    ...
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Failed to compile ");
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Comment: The e here contains whatever string the child throws, correct? So should that match the string that the testcase is asserting for?

Comment: I think what also needs to be handled is the difference between java.lang.Exception versus java.lang.error. I believe if I use throw e it is leading to the former while the latter is expected in the test case

Comment: The `e` is the `Exception` that the child would throw. An exception can have a message associated with it, for example `new IllegalArgumentException("cannot find file")`. The caller of the parent could catch the exception and inspect its message through `assertThrows`. It's best practice to throw a subclass of `Exception` instead of `Error`.

Comment: Understood. I have two stages of throws in place to reach back the test case. I am doing this as java.lang.error because that is the expected form in the test-case.  On second thought, the statement getStdErr() is looking what is there n the STDERR anyway, correct?

SO doing string matching in the 'e' to pass the assert statement is not required. rather the STDERR should match the test case string. That's what I am getting